# Function to change information on a data structure (C)

Tags: c, function, data-structures

I currently am developing an program for a school project that it displays a menu with the following options:
1-Add a vehicle;
2-Change information about a vehicle
3-Eliminate a vehicle;
4-List of lists.

*I'm probably going to spam a little bit these days cause it's a project that's worth 50% of the grade and I'm so far away from the main goal*

Anyway, 1 and 3 are done.
4 is far from done.
But I need your help with the option 2 bros.
*As I'm writting this I realized that I'm developing this program in a binary tree mode when I think I should use a linked list*

I'm going to drop you some code now:
This doesn't need intro

```
typedef struct Caravana
{
    char matricula[20];
    char marca[40];
    char modelo[45];
    char formato[20];
    int ano;
    int max_lugares;
    int area;
    int preco;
}CARAVANA;
```

Then, we have a function to insert the element on the tree

```
void inserirCaravana(NODO **raiz, CARAVANA newInfo)
{
    if (*raiz==NULL)
        {
            (*raiz)= criaElem(newInfo);
            return;
        }
    if (newInfo.matricula> (*raiz)->info.matricula)
        {
            inserirCaravana(&(*raiz)->direita, newInfo);
        }
    else
        {
            inserirCaravana(&(*raiz)->esquerda, newInfo);
        }
```

after that we reserve space and fulfill the element

```
NODO *criaElem(CARAVANA newInfo)
{
    NODO *novo= NULL;
    novo=(NODO *) calloc(1,sizeof(NODO));
    if (novo==NULL)
        {
            printf("<<<<<Out of memory>>>>>\n");
        }
    else 
        {
            novo->info=newInfo;
            novo->direita=NULL;
            novo->esquerda=NULL;
        }
    return novo;
    
}
```

**I was thinking to do a printf to ask for a license plate, use a strcmp,an if if it doesn't find it so it can return, and if it finds I must do something right?**

That's where you step in bros, thank you a lot

Comment: Hard to answer, but if you knw how to delete and add, update can be done by deleting previous and adding new version.
Use malloc insteaf of calloc, don't cast result of calloc or malloc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've made a binary tree of vehicles based on their "matricula" which I think means "license plate" or "registration."

You should ask the user for the matricula of the vehicle they want to change, then search for that record in your binary tree. It's just the same as inserting, except:

- The function will return `NODO *` or `Caravana *`.
- Before going right (direita) or left (esquerda), first check if the current vehicle has the matricula you're looking for, and if so, return it.
- If you reach a `NULL` node, just return `NULL`.
- You can just pass a `NODO *` instead of `NODO **` because you won't have to update it.

Once you've found the vehicle you want to edit, you can just replace the field values with whatever the user enters. Don't let the user change the matricula field, though, since that will alter where it should be in the tree. If you have to let the user change it, then you should remove the node from the tree and re-add it with the new matricula value.

There are a couple of issues with your insert function:

- You're using `>` to compare two strings. That doesn't work in C, use `strcmp` instead.
- You're passing in the Caravana by value so it's going to be copied every time the function invokes itself. It would be more efficient to allocate the `NODO` structure *before* calling the insert function, and just pass it as a `NODO *`.